# 3 Column Fluid Div Display Glitch: "Hanging" Individual Divs

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, fluid-layout, portfolio

I have a responsive fluid design portfolio with 3 columns. Something is wrong with the CSS that I am having trouble pinpointing.

If I have exactly 3 items on a row, it appears fine. However, if the last item ends on a line with only 1 or 2 columns, then the whole format gets distorted. This can be seen by resizing the browser.

If you can help me pinpoint the CSS fix for this, I will appreciate it GREATLY.

The example page is here: http://bit.ly/KzfN2g

I believe this is the main css style that is the culprit of the problem, however I could be wrong:

```
 .mosaic-block-three {
    margin-right:3%;
    width:29.3%;
    background:url("../img/progress.gif") no-repeat scroll center center #F5F5F5;
    border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px 0 #888888;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 40px 30px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:291px;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, this looks broken to me even without resizing the window. It's got row 1 fine, row 2 fine, then just one item on row 3. Then randomness. Using Firefox 12 on Win7 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using simple jQuery to get the height of the image on page load and declare the height in css, then get the height of the image on window resize and redeclare it in css

$j(document).ready(function() {

```
// Set portfolio image item height after images load, 

        $j(".mosaic-backdrop img").load(function(){
         var portfolioItemHeight =  $j(".mosaic-backdrop img").height();
         $j(".portfolio-three-item").css("height", portfolioItemHeight);
        });
// reset portfolio image item height each time window is maximized

        if(screen.width > 1200) {
            $j(".mosaic-backdrop img").load(function(){
             var portfolioItemHeight =  $j(".mosaic-backdrop img").height();
             $j(".portfolio-three-item").css("height", portfolioItemHeight);
            });

        }
// reset portfolio image item height each time window is resized

        $j(window).resize(function() {
         var portfolioItemHeightReized =    $j(".mosaic-backdrop img").height();
         $j(".portfolio-three-item").css("height", portfolioItemHeightReized);
     });

     });
```

Thank you, @kristina childs, for helping me realize it was that the height was not set properly!

Answer (score 0):

whoa, holy registered trademark batman! i would put a

```
<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

if i were you :) but to the question at hand...

why do you have so many lists with only one item? you've also got some styles in there that aren't defined, but i think your biggest problem is that you have items within

```
<li>
```

that are floated while the containing elements are not.

try floating .portfolio-three-item then clearing the contents within it. having floated elements inside non-floated elements (without using a clearing class or

```
<br clear="all" />
```

confuses the browser and it doesn't look as though any of the contents need to be floated.

Comment: Thanks. I removed all the ul,li tags and I floated the main item div to the left - However the outcome is exactly the same. Some lines don't float all the elements properly. Can you take a look again to see if I'm missing anything else?

Comment: the problem seems to stem from .portfolio-three-item. there is no height/width set for this container div, yet .mosaic-backdrop has height and width set for 100%. i fixed it by only setting a height for .portfolio-three-item. it looks like you're trying to make a stylesheet that works for mobile as well as screen? percentage heights didn't work so you'll have to set a hard height. i used 10em, but the ultimate size is up to you. 

you *may* be able to achieve a percentage height, but you will have to specify all heights of divs down to the body or even html level

Comment: if i'm right about the stylesheets, it may behoove you to make separate screen and mobile sheets for this one class

Comment: also, having the full resolution images in each of those sections causes the page to load REALLY slowly. you may want to opt for thumbnails instead

Comment: Thanks, I got it using jQuery! Excellent help!